# How to call a function from another file in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm making a Discord bot and I have two files. One called index.js & another called functions.js.
How do I run my function, from functions.js, in my main program?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const config = require("./config.json");
const sleep = require('sleep.js');
const func = require('./functions');
var days = 0;

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Bot has started, with ${client.users.cache.size} users, in ${client.channels.cache.size} channels of ${client.guilds.cache.size} guilds.`);
    func.Christmas()
    client.user.setActivity(days + ' days until Christmas!', { type: 'PLAYING', url: 'https://twitch.tv/itzp3nguin' });
});

client.login(config.token);
```

If I run that I get the error saying 'func.Christmas' is not a function...

Functions.js file: https://pastebin.com/xsJbD1Qa

Comment: What does `functions.js` look like?

Comment: Does your functions.js have something like this at the bottom: `module.exports = {Christmas, ...}`?

Comment: You will have to show us the relevant portions of `functions.js` before we can see how to help you.  If it properly exports `Christmas`, then it will all work just fine so apparently you are not exporting it properly.  Show us that code and we can help you more specifically.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xsJbD1Qa

Comment: Please include any additional clarifications in the question itself and not within a comment. And you need to export Christmas somehow, using either module.exports or ES6 export.

Comment: External link references for code that is required to understand the question are NOT ok here as the only source of the info.  That's because external links tend to break over time or the content gets changed, rendering the question useless as a long term reference.  Please paste all required code INTO the actual question itself!  Please fix your question.  People here were nice enough to look and answer anyway, though they should have insisted that you follow the proper procedure here as that's what keeps stackoverflow useful as a long term reference.  Please fix the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to the bottom of your function.js file:

```
module.exports = {Christmas}
```

Comment: that worked. lol however the actualy code inside the function doesn't lol.

Comment: @Mystik Oh well. At least you can call the function now.

Comment: yes thanks, I'll mark as answer when it lets me

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `module.exports = Christmas` at the end of the functions.js file. Otherwise Javascript (or Node.js in this case) doesn't know, what should be used when referencing this file.
In Javascript you always have to specify which functions/ variables should be accessible from outside the current file by exporting them via `module.exports ...` or `export ...`.